# Set background of every gridView item?

Tags: android, android-gridview, baseadapter

I have an Adapter, and I want to know how I can set the background of each gridView item and set up a pattern? I have three backgrounds, and I want to set the first item to bg1, second to bg2, third to bg3, fourth to bg1, fifth to bg2, sixth to bg3, ect.

My guess is that this is done under getView(), but I need some guidance. Here is what I have so far.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.llBackground = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llBackground);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mArrayList.get(position).getWebsite()).placeholder(R.drawable.old_graphic).centerCrop().resize(100, 100).into(holder.ivItem);
    holder.llBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg2);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of drawables on your values.xml like

```
<string-array name="grid_view_backgrounds">
    <item>@drawable/bg1</item>
    <item>@drawable/bg2</item>
    <item>@drawable/bg3</item>
</string-array>
```

Then keep a reference to the TypedArray on your adappter:

```
final TypedArray backgrounds = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.grid_view_backgrounds);
```

Then just use the position of your element to calculate to which element of the array corresponds, like:

```
holder.llBackground.setBackgroundResource(
    backgrounds.getResourceId(position % backgrounds.length(), 0)
)
```

Comment: Interesting. I will try this. Thank you. +1 for answering

Comment: No idea, wasn't mine, but take my +1 to make some balance